# Making Spotify Embeds Responsive

Tags: embed, responsive-design, spotify

Working on a responsive design at the moment and needs to have a responsive Spotify embed. I tried with just css (didn't work), then used fitvids.js (as a weird janky solution) which kind of works but only on initial page load and sometimes puts a big margin at the bottom.

See here for an example or see the code at the bottom:
http://codepen.io/oosabaj/full/keEBu

Dave Rupert (maker of fitvids) said "Looks like Spotify is doing its own resize "magic" so it probably won't work."

Any dev's (maybe spotify ones) got a solution?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{
      background: #e0d7d4;
    }

    #wrap {
      width: 900px;
      min-height: 200px;
      margin: 15px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
      #wrap {
        width: 700px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
      #wrap {
        width: 500px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
      #wrap {
        width: 300px;
      }
    }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fitvidsjs.com/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
$("#wrap").fitVids({ customSelector: "iframe[src^='https://embed.spotify.com']"});
      });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
    <iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:erebore:playlist:788MOXyTfcUb1tdw4oC7KJ&amp;theme=white" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up writing a little jQuery snippet to resize the player and reload the iframe on window load and resize. A very hacky solution but it works. Just include the code on whatever page you have Spotify embeds. If anyone has a better solution I'd be glad to hear it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]').each( function() {
    $(this).css('width',$(this).parent(1).css('width'));
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]').each( function() {
    $(this).css('width',$(this).parent(1).css('width'));
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/jbasoo/pen/gDkoc

Comment: Is the CSS just not working on your site? It seems to be working on your codepen demo. I'm assuming you've tried something like: width:100% !important;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how best to incorporate this into your design, but the Spotify widget can be pretty picky about its proportions. They give min and max width and height on the [documentation page](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/documentation/), but more importantly it contains this little gem:

> The larger player will be rendered if the given height is 80 pixels greater than the given width. Otherwise the compact player will be rendered.

That *sounds* like it should only affect which player version is shown. In reality, I've found that not conforming to that restriction across the board results in some funky display glitches - parts of the player being hidden, big chunks of whitespace in the iframe, etc.

I've got the widget displaying pretty well with a variety of playlists in a dynamically-sized shadowbox, but since that shadowbox is launched with javascript I have full control over the width and height. I'm able to always set the width to height - 80.

It also doesn't handle resizing of the window well. The iframe resizes perfectly, but its contents don't redraw. The actual widget page seems to calculate its dimensions based on available space in the iframe when it initially loads, and doesn't watch for page resize events. You can see that's the case even without the iframe by loading [a widget url](https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify%3atrack:0CCcVq5Y0LR2x2KUPiCyTR) directly. If that's a big concern for you, maybe your outer page can use javascript to watch for a resize, and use that event to trigger a refresh of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I merged this two solutions:

- https://gist.github.com/mennolui/687fdc251c6a64289da5
- https://codepen.io/jbasoo/pen/gDkoc

I changed that the height is also responsive.

An example [here](https://codepen.io/Suplanus/pen/bZKqVo).

So I endet up with this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Make Spotify fit initial layout */
    respondify();
});


$(window).resize(function() {
    /* Make Spotify fit layout on resize */
    respondify();
});


function respondify() {
    $('body').find('iframe[src*="spotify.com/"]').each(function() {
        var w = $(this).parent(1).width();
        $(this).css('width', w + 'px');

    var h = $(window).height();
    $(this).css('height', h + 'px');

        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    });

}
```